# Splitting a list of strings using cut - KDB

Tags: kdb

For the following list:

```
q)a:("ua@1100@1";"sba@2220@2";"r@4444@a")
```

I want following output :

```
("1100@1";"2220@2";"4444@a")
```

`?` gives first index of `@`

```
q)(a?\:"@")
2 3 1`
```

but using `cut` does not give the desired result :

```
q)(a?\:"@")cut'a
(("ua";"@1";"10";"0@";"1");("sba";"@22";"20@";"2");("r";"@";"4";"4";"4";"4";"@";"a"))`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also parse the data rather than drop chars from each string.
It'll be somewhat more efficient if your dataset is large.

```
q)("J@*"0:/:a)[;1]
"1100@1"
"2220@2"
"4444@a"
```

Notice I've set the 'key' to 'J' which will result in nulls in your example case, but you only care about the values anyway.

If you can join (sv) the strings together, it'll be even better too

```
q)last "J@;"0:";" sv a
"1100@1"
"2220@2"
"4444@a"
```

HTH,
Sean

Comment: Nice! Worth mentioning that this works only for newer versions (certain releases of 3.4 onwards). Also, in the first case for the outputs to be true strings of type 10h you could do ```("J@*"0:/:a)[;1;0]```

Answer (score 1):

When the left argument of `cut` is atom , `cut` behaves differently than `_`.

```
q)2 cut 2 3 4 5 6
(2 3;4 5;,6)

q)2 _ 2 3 4 5 6
4 5 6
```

Use `_` to cut the string

```
q)(1+a?\:"@")_'a
("1100@1";"2220@2";"4444@a")
```

or

```
q)"@"sv/:1_/:"@" vs/:a
("1100@1";"2220@2";"4444@a")
```